# How to divide cells instead of spanning the multiple cells in SpreadSheetView?

Tags: javafx-8, controlsfx

I would like to divide 1 cell into multiple cells instead of using the row and column spans. Because I want to be able to change the cell content dynamically after I use `setGrid()` method.

Even though I use **SpreadsheetCellType.LIST** to create cell, it just shows the first value of the list and it does not seperate cells. I could not find any information in the document ; https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetCellType.ListType.html.

What I want is someting like this (3rd row , 1st column):
[image: Multiple Cell Example]

Is this possible ?

Comment: I don't understand your need. SpreadsheetView is a spreadsheet just like Excel.. One cell is only containing... one cell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, with different approach . Instead of creating 2 cells , I created ListView for each cell and set as graphic .

```
SpreadsheetCell cell = SpreadsheetCellType.STRING.createCell(x, y, 1, 1, "");
ListView<SpreadListCell> listView = new ListView<>(valuesList);
listView.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
listView.setPrefHeight(valuesList.size()*24);
cell.setGraphic(listView);
```